# How to move an item in an array without updating all the others?

Tags: javascript, sortablejs

I have an Array composed of Objects, such as :

```js
const items = [
    { id: 0, title: 'Object 1', sort: 0 },
    { id: 1, title: 'Object 2', sort: 1 },
    { id: 2, title: 'Object 3', sort: 2 },
    { id: 3, title: 'Object 4', sort: 3 },
    { id: 4, title: 'Object 5', sort: 4 },
    { id: 5, title: 'Object 6', sort: 5 },
    { id: 6, title: 'Object 7', sort: 6 },
    { id: 7, title: 'Object 8', sort: 7 },
    { id: 8, title: 'Object 9', sort: 8 }
]
```

Using a dragging library (Sortable.js via VueDragguable), I receive the "onChange" event, which contains the following details :

- element: The element moved, for instance, `{ id: 2, title: 'Object 3', sort: 2 }`
- newIndex: The new position for this element, such as 6
- oldIndex: The old position, here, 3

When a `change` event is fired (with the move specifically, not `add` or `remove`), I'd like to update the `sort` property in the objects that are affected by the change, by modyfing the least number of objects (in order to reduce the number of writes in the database).

How could I do that?

Note: The "sort" parameter here is arbitrary. If a better way is possible, I can update the code accordingly.

Comment: acually i see an array. what data structure have you in your db?

Comment: You seem to ask multiple things. If this is only about the array data structure management, then please remove the extra layer of Sortable, Vue, DOM, onChange event, database, and simplify the question to just JavaScript. If however your question really is about keeping a list sorted in Vue, then please focus on that, providing the HTML and all that is necessary to reproduce the issue you have.

Comment: A different approach would be to also have a 'parent' object that contains a list of ordered ids, and just update that one object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, you can simply move the item in your array to the right place using the splice method and then check if your items have the right place.

You can find all wrong items using the filter method with a comparison with those indexes.

```js
const items = [
    { id: 0, title: 'Object 1', sort: 0 },
    { id: 1, title: 'Object 2', sort: 1 },
    { id: 2, title: 'Object 3', sort: 2 },
    { id: 3, title: 'Object 4', sort: 3 },
    { id: 4, title: 'Object 5', sort: 4 },
    { id: 5, title: 'Object 6', sort: 5 },
    { id: 6, title: 'Object 7', sort: 6 },
    { id: 7, title: 'Object 8', sort: 7 },
    { id: 8, title: 'Object 9', sort: 8 }
]

const event = {
  element: { id: 2, title: 'Object 3', sort: 2 },
  newIndex: 6,
  oldIndex: 2
}

// removing the item
items.splice(event.oldIndex, 1)

//replacing it
items.splice(event.newIndex - 1, 0, event.element)

const itemsToUpdateInDatabase = items.filter((item, index) => item.sort !== index)

console.log(itemsToUpdateInDatabase)
```